# how to get string values using index method in Python

Tags: python, indexing, split

I need to parse text of text file into two categories:

```
University
Location(Example: Lahore, Peshawar, Jamshoro, Faisalabad)
```

but the text file contain following text:
"Imperial College of Business Studies, Lahore"
"Government College University Faisalabad"
"Imperial College of Business Studies Lahore"
"University of Peshawar, Peshawar"
"University of Sindh, Jamshoro"

Code:

```
for l in content:
    rep = l.replace('"','')
    if ',' in rep:
        uni = rep.split(',')[0]
        loc = rep.split(',')[-1].strip()
    else:
        loc = rep.split(' ')[-1].strip()
        uni = rep.split(' ').index(loc)
```

It Return following Output, Where 3 and 5 are index value before cities:

- 3 represents Government College University
- 5 represents Imperial College of Business Studies

Uni: Imperial College of Business Studies Loc: Lahore
Uni: 3 Loc: Faisalabad
Uni: 5 Loc: Lahore
Uni: University of Peshawar Loc: Peshawar
Uni: University of Sindh Loc: Jamshoro

**I want the Program to return me the string value against index value 3 & 5.**

Comment: I don't understand "return me the string value against index value 3 & 5". Can you give an example of the output you want to see?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/32095824/4014959

Comment: 3 and 5 shows that at what index is location on.
 index: 0              1            2                3
Government College University Faisalabad

 index: 0       1     2       3           4           5
Imperial College of Business Studies Lahore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case where there is no comma, the lines

```
loc = rep.split(' ')[-1].strip()
uni = rep.split(' ').index(loc)
```

first find the location as the last element of the string, then tell you at what index the string occurs.  What you want is everything but the last word in the string which you can get as

```
uni = ' '.join(rep.split()[:-1])
```

It might be better just to replace the , by '' to begin with so that there was only one case to deal with.  Also, my inclination is to split the string only once.

```
words = rep.split()   # the default is to split at whitespace
loc = words[-1]
uni = ' '.join(words[:-1])
```

So, I would write the loop like this:

```
for l in content:
    rep = l.strip('"').replace(',','')
    words = rep.split()  
    loc = words[-1]
    uni = ' '.join(words[:-1])
    print(uni, loc)
```

This prints

```
('Imperial College of Business Studies', 'Lahore')
('Government College University', 'Faisalabad')
('Imperial College of Business Studies', 'Lahore')
('University of Peshawar', 'Peshawar')
('University of Sindh', 'Jamshoro')
```

which I take it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

just cycle thru and take the last element as location:

```
content = [
    "Government College University Faisalabad",
    "Imperial College of Business Studies Lahore",
    "University of Peshawar, Peshawar",
    "University of Sindh, Jamshoro"]

locs = [l.split()[-1] for l in content]
print locs
```

['Faisalabad', 'Lahore', 'Peshawar', 'Jamshoro']